# Deleting facebook user role in app when user hasn't yet accepted the invitation (pending) using facebook graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As the title suggests, I'm having problems deleting users that have not yet accepted the role on my apps.

When I make the delete request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{app-id}/roles/?method=DELETE&user={userId}&access_token={adminAccessToken}
```

I get the answer:

```
{"success": true}
```

But the user is still in the roles tab of the app with the "(pending)" tag beside.

Is there any other way to do this using facebook-graph?

Comment: I’d suggest you go file a bug report and ask them to fix this. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: You are right, it seems that it's a bug. Submit an answer if you want and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug.

I’d suggest you go file a bug report and ask them to fix this. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

---

(I don’t like giving short answers like this, especially if it doesn’t actually solve the problem. But if you want something to accept … ;-) If someone can come up with a better answer, that’d be fine by me.)

Comment: Or un-delete your own answer – then you’ll get a +1 from me for linking to the bug report.